# Angular UI Select2 initialization fails

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm failing to get Angular UI Select2 module to work. Simplest example I could think of is below, derived from AngularJS tutorial.

Directions on Github project (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) state, that I only need to include jQuery, Angular and Angular UI's select2.js. But then I get only errors:
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'

Including Select2 there is no errors, but I get select tag's placeholder text as a link, then two empty text input fields a regular select dropdown. When I choose something in select dropdown, it's value replaces the placeholder text. Clicking the link empties the page, so does trying to input something to text boxes.

I have tested with multiple browsers and platforms, using Yeoman's generator-angular as a base. I tried a much older version of Angular UI's select2.js, but the behaviour did not change. Searching did not turn up anything relevant, and working examples I found are prior to Angular UI's breakup into modules.

What I am doing wrong or is this a bug?

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="anguish">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<select ui-select2 ng-model="select2" data-placeholder="Pick a number">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
    <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

foo.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('anguish', ['ui.select2'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.select2 = null;
    $scope.select2Options = {
        allowClear:true
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including `select2.js` before `angular.js` if you are getting 'has no method select2'.

Also, you will need the `select2.css` file. It's not going to style itself magically :)

Comment: Duh. Well. Of course. Thank you. I could have sworn I had some CSS there at some point, but that probably was from Angular UI's complete package... Live and learn. I'll try to get this changed in project's Github directions.